# I'm trying to find an alien romance movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

This is a movie that I watched a long time ago as a kid. I remember there being an alien prince who crashed landed on Earth with his faithful servant. They were being protected by a human girl and her family in their house from the government that was after the alien.

The human girl then helps nurse the alien prince back to health while they are hiding out. They start to fall in love and I think in the end the girl decides to go with him to his home planet to be his queen.

Comment: When were you a kid I.e. when did you watch this? How does the servant play into the film? Do we see the two leave Earth at the end? Did they fix the ship or another come to pick them up? If you remember anything else please [edit] those details into the question.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.